# C++ How to implement A* with new nodes calculated on the fly?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, a-star

I am trying to use A* for a search problem where I begin in a certain state of a matrix (e.g. all zeros), and each step I can perform one of several transformations on the matrix and I want to arrive in another state of the matrix (e.g. all ones). The search nodes also store some other auxiliary objects.

As a result,

- The search nodes are fairly big (containing the matrix state + other objects at each step)
- Since the search space is also big, I don't have a "Graph" object, I simply generate new nodes on the fly in each step.

In A*, I need to have a map from each Node to its gScore. Normally, if I were searching over a static graph object, I could just use an unordered_map with pointer keys, i.e.

```
unordered_map<Node*, int> gScore;
```

But since I am generating new Nodes on the fly, each new Node will have a new memory address. So I could have two Nodes with the exact same state and different addresses.

This is also a problem for the priority queue

```
boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<Node*, boost::heap::compare<mycomp> > pq;
```

because with decrease-key I once again run into the above problem - the priority queue always thinks the new node is different because it has a different memory address.

I'm sure this problem is not uncommon (i.e. search with big nodes calculated on the fly), so how do people normally deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I could have two Nodes with the exact same state and different addresses.

If that's all that your problem was, the answer would simply be a matter of using a `unordered_set<Node>` instead of just newing Nodes, and make sure that your `Node` class has a proper hash function associated with it. This will take care of dedupping your nodes.

The next question is: How much of that latent search space are you expecting to traverse? On paper, it's always possible that you'll hit a degenerate case where you need to traverse more nodes than you can fit in memory, which is going to be a problem.

To address this, there are two main approaches:

1. Choose an arbitrary number of nodes to open / memory to consume before giving up on the search and treat it as an effectively unsolvable case.
2. Actually search through that latent search space until a solution is found. In that case, A* is not going to cut it, and you'll need a more memory efficient algorithm such as [Iterative-deepening A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_A*).

Comment: Oh right, I was assuming that `unordered_map<Node, int>` would double the memory requirements. But I guess unordered_map isn't actually storing the keys, just the hash function and hashed values, right? Thanks for the other suggestions too. I will probably have to look into iterative-deepening A*.

Comment: @Paradox Oh! it does make a copy of the full object in the set/map. The idea is that this object **replaces** the one on the heap. It's the same amount of data, just organized differently.